# Ruby-Java bridge JDBC Connection Rails

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to create a connection with postgresql using a gem called RJB (Ruby-Java bridge) by importing the "Class" class and the "DriverManager" class, and running the following code:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")
url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database"
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, 'root', '123')
```

but I get the following error: 
SQLException: No suitable driver found for `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database`
is there a way to make it work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the gem? Meaning have you ran the command that installs the gem on the gemfile you're working on.

Comment: What gem are you talking  about? Postgresql driver? If so, that wouldn't really help, considering I'm connecting using a JDBC connection on a non jruby project. As for the jar file for the driver, I'm loading it using Rjb.add_jar and Rjb.include